# Class as members of other classes : Create a constructor that takes all data

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes Books and Author. One of members of Books is of type Author.
On Class Books I want to have a Constructor that takes all the parameters for book and for author :
This is my code :

```
class author
{
private :
    string name;
    string email;
public :
    string get_name(){return name;}
    string get_email(){return email;}
    void set_name(string name){this->name=name;}
    void set_email(string email){this->email=email;}

    author(string name,string email)
    {
        this->name=name;
        this->email=email;
    }
}

class book
{
private :
    string title;
    int year;
    author auth;
public:
    string get_title(){return title;}
    int get_year(){return year;}
    void set_title(string title){this->title=title;}
    void set_year(float year){this->year=year;}

    book(string title, int year):author(string name,string email)
    {
       this->title=title;
       this->year=year;
       ???????
    }
}
```

I don't know how can i change the constructor of book in order that it takes all the parameter for book and for the author?

Thank you !

Comment: You have to specify them all "by hand" - or take an `author` as parameter into the constructor

Comment: One question you should probably ask yourself: Should the book really *contain* an author, i.e., have an author live inside the book? Should the book not rather just hold a reference to its author?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel and how can i do this ?

Comment: @antoni are you familiar with pointers or references? You would just have your `book` have a pointer or reference to an `author` object as member instead of an `author` itself…

Answer (score 0):

In this case, one can use *member initializer lists*; these are special comma-separated lists of expressions, given after a `:` in the constructor body, in the form `member_variable(value)` or `member_variable(values, to, pass, to, constructor)`. Using this construction, your code would resemble the following:

```
class Author {
    string _name;
    string _email;
public:
    Author(string name, string email)
        : _name(name)
        , _email(email)
    {/* nothing to do now */}
};

class Book {
    string _title;
    int _year;
    Author _author;

public:
    Book(string title, int year, Author author)
        : _author(author)
        , _title(title)
        , _year(year)
    {/* nothing to do now */}
    Book(string title, int year, string author_name, string author_email)
        : _author(author_name, author_email)
        , _title(title)
        , _year(year)
    {/* nothing to do now */}
};
```

However, this is a problematic solution, in situations such as the following:

```
Author bookish_writer("Bookish Writer", "bookishwriter@example.com");
Book a_book("A Book", 2019, bookish_writer);
// But what if I want to change bookish_writer's e-mail?
bookish_writer.set_email("the.real.bookish.writer@example.com");
// This will print bookishwriter@example.com
cout << a_book.get_author().get_email();
```

Using the above code, the Author object will be *passed by value* to the constructor, or created within the Book object.

One solution would be to use pointers:

```
class Book {
    Author * _author;
    string _title;
    int _year;
public:
    Book(string title, int year, Author * author)
        : _author(author)
        , _year(year)
        , _title(title)
    {}
}
```

In which case you would use:

```
Author bookish_writer("Bookish Writer", "bookishwriter@example.com");
Book a_book("A Book", 2019, &bookish_writer);
```

Comment: sorry , you have changed your code . Using your previous code was working. Now i don't know how do do i call the constructor with both data for book and author. I've used : book book1("Title1",1985,Author("Name1" ,"123@yahoo.com")) , but i'm getting an error : Could not find a match for Book ::Book(string,int,author))

Comment: As @Michael Kenzel said earlier, though, you might be better off doing this with pointers or references

Comment: ok , but i've tried to use your new version before , but i had that problem.How can i do ? some help ???

Comment: Edited with a little bit on how pointers would be used, and why they're useful